# How to organize internal dependencies in an R package?

Tags: r

I am creating an R package with a series of **internal** dependencies. Specifically I have 2 analytical functions (call them FA1 and FA2) that depend on 2 functions that do some data treatment (call demo FT1 and FT2). My question is:

1. How should I structure my package in such a way that FA1 and FA2 call FT1 and FT2 ? Should I define an .r file for each (FA1.r , FA2.r , FT1.r , FT2.r) If so how can I call FT1 and FT2 to  FA1.r , FA2.r ?
2. Or in each FA1.r and FA2.r I should also define FT1.r , FT2.r ?

EDIT:
based on some comments below a 3rd point should be asked that can help settle the issue:

3. How can I control which functions are seen by the user and which are just for internal package purposes ?

Thanks.

Comment: In your package, it doesn't really matter whether you define the functions in different files or the same file; that's sort of a matter of taste.  When the package is built, all functions you define are available to all other functions in your package.  Only the ones exported from the namespace are available to users without calling package:::function().

Comment: A good reference to guide you on this matter could maybe be [this R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/internal-functions-in-r-packages/). Personnally, I would opt for solution 1 and manage the exporting via roxygen2 keywords.

Comment: Ok so how can I control which ones are exported and available to users and which are not?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the course of action that I decided to take was:

make FT1.r , FT2.r unexported functions (by adding a dot in front of their definition, that is .FT1.r and .FT2.r on a separate file).

Thanks for the help guys.